# Peer to Peer network bandwitth

Tags: distributed-computing, p2p, distributed-system, bandwidth

I am working on a project that involves a peer to peer network.  Someone raised concerns that we may be expecting a larger bandwidth than is reasonable.

Suppose we had a large number of registered nodes (in the thousands, possibly 10,000), and these nodes constantly are receiving data which they wish to propagate around the network.  The data doesn't have to get to every node, but we would like it to get to most of them.

In general, how much data creation and transmission could be handled reasonably as the number of nodes increases?  I am hoping that, in my case, the answer is more than 50 MB/minute (as this is the maximum amount of data my system is expected to create), but I don't have a basis for comparison.